# UITableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath stops working if you return an empty array

Tags: ios, uitableview, action

I have a UITableView for which I have added some custom slide out buttons. These all work as expected. There is however a scenario in my table where a row can be in a state where none of the slide out buttons are relevant and so I have been returning an empty array of actions so the slide out buttons wont appear. Unfortunately once this occurs the UITableView stops calling my editActionsForRowAtIndexPath effectively disabling slide out buttons for all rows in my table ... and it seems permanent until the app is restarted.

Is this expected behaviour?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]?
{
    if mydata[indexPath.row].EditAvailable()
    {
        var editAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Edit", handler: editHandler)
        return [editAction]
    }
    else
    { 
        return []
    }
}
```

Comment: A [long shot](http://nshipster.com/at-compiler-directives/), but try return @[]

Comment: I recognise the @ symbol from objective-c ... but is it valid in swift?

Comment: I thought i have seen it used in swift somewhere around here, cant find it now though (for creating and initializing arrays). Is mydata  always an accessible array with mydata.length==indexpath number of rows?

Comment: My data is a full copy of the data for all the rows and not part of the problem. The problem is the returned empty action array causing the whole table (not just the row indicated by the indexPath) to stop allowing the swipe action.

Answer (score 23):

The way I solved this problem was to implement the function,

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool
```

Here, you should just return false if you don't want the expected row to have the swipe feature.

So you code would look something like this

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
  return mydata[indexPath.row].EditAvailable()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]?
{
  var editAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Edit", handler: editHandler)
  return [editAction]
}
```

The editActionsForRowAtIndexPath is then only called for the ones that you indicated are editable.

Answer (score 7):

Please try to use `tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:`.
You can control the on/off of the slide itself.

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (/* mydata[indexPath.row].EditAvailable() */) {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
    } else {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
    }
}
```

(I tested in objective-c)

Answer (score 6):

Avoid passing empty Arrays at -

> tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath

Better do the condition check in -

> tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath

Format your code like this :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        if mydata[indexPath.row].EditAvailable()  {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]?
    {
        var editAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Edit", handler: editHandler)
        return [editAction]
    }
```

Comment: +1 for this. Great. My app crashes when you pass an empty array inside `tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath`. I think it makes sense because **edit** means that there should be something already available to edit. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

First, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath should return nil and not [] when then are no actions.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]?
{
    if mydata[indexPath.row].EditAvailable()
    {
        var editAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Edit", handler: editHandler)
        return [editAction]
    }
    else
    { 
        return nil
    }
}
```

Second, you must implement editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath to disable the default "Delete" action for the other rows.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    if mydata[indexPath.row].EditAvailable() {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete
    }
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.None
}
```

Thanks [luciano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1015951/luciano) for the tip empty array/nil tip

Answer (score 2):

In iOS9.3, "canEditRowAtIndexPath" doesn't work!!!

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

So, the following code works for me. Only two methods should be implemented.

```
-(NSArray *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(//not editable){
        return nil;
    }
    return @[//your actions];
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if(//not editable){
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
    }
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}
```

Comment: Yeah noticed this aswell, Apple y u do this?

Answer (score 1):

You should not return an empty array for the actions at editActionsForRowAtIndexPath. If you want to make the row not editable...
return false at canEditRowAtIndexPath. Once you return an empty array, all rows stop showing the swipe buttons. Its a strange behavior, i don't know whether its a glitch or as intended.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented similar selective usage of actions for some tableCell using ob-c(have not tested in swift) a while ago but put the selectiveness in handleSwipe, below i have an action for all except the last one:

```
- (void)handleSwipeLeft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
    CGPoint location = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *swipedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];
    if(!(swipedIndexPath.row<[coreDataHelper getAllTimerLists].count) ){
        [self.tableView setEditing:!self.tableView.editing animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Does this help you or do you need multiple different actions array, as opposed to this which only has one array and inactivates/activates it?

Comment: This is an interesting alternative proposal. If i understand it correctly you are intercepting the swipe event before it even gets to the tableview and hence prevent editActionsForRowAtIndexPath from ever being called which prevents the return of an empty actions array and hence avoids the behaviour.